# C# Google Cloud DataStore Query Filter no matching index found

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I've encountered a strange situation while I'm using Google Cloud DataStore query.

Here's my code:

```
var cutoff = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30);
var query = new Query("message")
            {
            Filter = Filter.And(
                Filter.Equal("type", type), 
                Filter.Equal("receiver", receiver), 
                Filter.Equal("sender", sender), 
                Filter.GreaterThanOrEqual("created", cutoff))
            };
// type is integer, receiver and sender is string
```

The exception log shows below:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=FailedPrecondition, Detail="no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: message
  properties:
  - name: receiver
  - name: sender
  - name: type
  - name: created
")
```

I've checked several times that all of the properties are really exist.

Below shows why I call it strange:

When I remove the property `created` it worked fine:

```
var query = new Query("message")
            {
            Filter = Filter.And(
                Filter.Equal("type", type), 
                Filter.Equal("receiver", receiver), 
                Filter.Equal("sender", sender)
            };
 // works fine
```

That direct me to think about the property `created` is the key point.

But when I use only `created`, it worked fine however.

```
var query = new Query("message")
            {
            Filter = Filter.And(
                Filter.GreaterThanOrEqual("created", cutoff))
            };
// works fine too
```

I don't have a clue what's happening.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've solved the problem myself.

The message did show that I didn't create an index properly to DataStore.

[Here is how to create and upload the index file(index.yaml).](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/indexref)

After I reset the index, it works fine as I expect.